# HOW to write select query in java using jdbc where to need to check if COLUMN IS NULL?

Tags: java, oracle, jdbc

Trying to write condition where  ind is null in the select query in java using jdbc oracle driver.

code :

Done all the DB connectivity

```
info.add("CN");
info.add("NULL");
```

Tried:

```
ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select COUNT(*) from TABLENAME where A='" + info.get(i) +  " and  ind is'" +info.get(i+1) + " '");
```

Note: using oracle driver JDBC API.

Taking the null value from array list.but it does not fetch proper values from DB.

code:

Done all the DB connectivity

```
info.add("CN");
info.add("NULL");

ResultSet rs1 = st.executeQuery("select COUNT(*) from TABLENAME where A='" + info.get(i) +  " and  ind IS '" +info.get(i+1) + " '");
```

I expect the output like count(no of rows):

BAsic sql query if used in DB:

```
select COUNT(*) 
from TABLENAME 
where A= 'a'   
 and  ind IS null;
```

Comment: what is datatype of info

Comment: Do **not** concatenate values like that into a SQL string. Learn to properly use a `PreparedStatement`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First handling NULL is different than handling a value:

```
ind IS NULL
ind = '...'
```

This makes it difficult to use a prepared statement. But a PreparedStatement should be used, not only for securite (against *SQL injection*) but also to escape single quotes and such. And is type-safe in that it uses types & conversions.

Oracle SQL has a defect in that it does not distinghuish between NULL and '', so you could go for '' instead. Oracle independent would be:

```
// Typed fields:
String a = ...;
int n = ...;
String ind = null;

String sql = ind == null
    ? "select COUNT(*) from TABLENAME where A=? and n=? and ind is null"
    : "select COUNT(*) from TABLENAME where A=? and n=? ind = ?";
try (PreparedStatement stmt = new PreparedStatement(sql)) {
   stmt.setString(1, a);
   stmt.setInt(2, n);
   if (ind != null) {
       stmt.setString(3, ind);
   }
   try (ResultSet rs = stmt.executeQuery()) {
       long count = rs.next() ? rs.getLong(1) : 0L;

       return count;
   }
}
```

Try-with-resources closes statement and result set, also with thrown exception or return in the middle.

For a general Object list, one could use one for loop constructing the SQL template, and a second for setting the PreparedStatement's fields.

Answer (score 0):

This part:

```
" and  ind is'" +info.get(i+1) + " '");
```

generates the following SQL:

```
  and ind is 'NULL ';
```

which is wrong because it will throw an error:

> ORA-00908: missing NULL keyword

You need to change that to:

```
" and ind is " +info.get(i+1));
```

but then it won't work any more for not null values.